# Cómo usar replace en javascript para '><' o para '/div' de manera global con /g

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

```
cadena = cadena.replace('/div>', "");
```

Al usar este código, me reemplaza sólo una. Al querer hacerlo de manera global se desactiva

```
cadena = cadena.replace(//div>/g, "");
```

`cadena = cadena.replace('><', "");` no lo hace en la cadena que tengo que es un `string` de un archivo de texto que leí de un `html`

El primero ya me salio con este codigo
cadena = cadena.replace(new RegExp("", 'g'), "");

pero el segundo no lo hace y quiero cambiar "><" esto ya lo intente con todos y ninguno lo hace porque sera??????

no no tiene espacios en blanco estoy leyendo una tabla que se creo desde html y por cuestiones del cliente tengo que hacer esto obligatoriamente en cada  significa que es un espacio en blanco yo pense cambiando cada >< por >blanco< que asi quiere el cliente que aparezca

Comment: Porque probablemente tengas espacios en blanco entre cada uno: `cadena.replace(/>\s*</g, "")` ... Sin embargo, sería mejor que expliques qué estás intentando hacer. Reemplazar una cadena directamente es código que funciona hoy pero que se rompe mañana. Deberías usar el DOM para procesar HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para reemplazar todas las ocurrencias de `><` o `/div>`, el único caracter que hay que escapar en este caso es la barra `/`, ya que es el delimitador que se usa para iniciar y terminar la expresión regular. La expresión regular quedaría:

```js
cadena = cadena.replace(/\/div>|></g, "");
```

O, si también se desea que ignore mayúsculas y minúsculas:

```js
cadena = cadena.replace(/\/div>|></gi, "");
```

---

Estos son los [metacaracteres](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Utilizando_caracteres_especiales) en regex que tendrás que escapar con una barra (`\`) si quisieras usarlos dentro de un patrón como literales:

```
/  .  ?  *  +  ^  $  [  \  (  )  {  |
```

---

> **Nota:** Tengo que avisarte que las expresiones regulares son muy poco recomendadas para procesar HTML por muchos motivos. Existen mejores métodos para trabajar con HTML como **[DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/Add-ons/Code_snippets/HTML_to_DOM)**. Y ahí, depende de qué estés intentando lograr: ya sea eliminar las etiquetas html, obtener el contenido de texto de un elemento, modificar una etiqueta, etc.
>
> Por ejemplo, si quisieras eliminar todos los tags y quedarte con el texto:
>
> ```js
> var textoHTML = "<div id='un-div'>Texto <b>dentro</b> del div</div>";
>
> //Generamos un documento
> var html = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
> var doc  = html.documentElement;
>
> //Cargamos nuestro string
> doc.innerHTML = textoHTML;
>
> //Obtenemos el contenido sin tags
> var textoSinTags = doc.innerText;
> console.log(textoSinTags);
> ```
>
> O sólo obtener el texto del primer `<div>`:
>
> ```js
> var textoHTML = "Antes.. <div id='un-div'>Texto<!--comentario--> del div</div>Bla";
>
> var html = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(),
>     doc  = html.documentElement;
> doc.innerHTML = textoHTML;
>
> //Obtenemos el contenido del primer div sin tags
> var primerDiv = doc.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
> console.log(primerDiv.innerText);
> ```
>
> Para más información de los métodos que podés usar y la compatibilidad: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document

Answer (score 3):

Si estás tratando de excluir todo el Html del div puedes usar jquery

```
$('<div>Mi contenido</div>').text()
```

o

```
$(cadena).text()
```

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias formas de hacer `replaceAll` en javascript:

## Regex:

Donde el caracter `|` define las opciones:

```js
var texto = "<div>Hola/div> mu/div>><><ndo</div>//div>div>"
console.log(
  texto.replace(new RegExp("/div>|><", 'g'), "")
)
```

## Split/Join:

Donde partes y juntas por las diferentes opciones, [menos performante](https://jsperf.com/split-join-vs-regex-replace) y mas oscuro de entender. Pero es una tecnica conocida.

```js
var texto = "<div>Hola/div> mu/div>><><ndo</div>//div>div>"
console.log(
  texto.split("/div>").join("").split("><").join("")
)
```

Algunos te diran que no es una buena practica extender el prototipo de un objeto, pero es muy conveniente.

```js
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(buscar, remplazar) {
  return this.replace(new RegExp(buscar, 'g'), remplazar);
}

var texto = "<div>Hola/div> mu/div>><><ndo</div>//div>div>"

console.log(
  texto.replaceAll("/div>|><","")
)
```

Comment: Para pasar un string como texto literal al constructor RegExp, se deberían escapar los caracteres especiales: `buscar.replace(/[.?*+^$[\\(){|]/g, "\\$&")`

Comment: "Algunos te diran que no es una buena practica extender el prototipo de un objeto" Sip, si todos los hicieramos cualquiera podría terminar rompiendo tu código. Aquí hay un artículo al respecto http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/ :)

Answer (score 0):

la respuesta al

```
cadena = cadena.replace('/div>', "");
```

fue

```
cadena = cadena.replace(new RegExp("</div>", 'g'), "");
```

y la respuesta a

```
cadena = cadena.replace('><', "");
```

fue tomar mas  caracteres

```
cadena = cadena.replace(new RegExp("<td></td>", 'g'), "<td>white</td>");
```

gracias a todos por su ayuda